# Explanations OAuth protocol Digging Deeper Documentation

Tags: integration, oauth2

In the documentation it says that "Apps that use OAuth can also directly authenticate and access Salesforce resources without a user’s presence". What does it mean?Is it not necessary create a Salesforce's user whit Salesforce license type? Is only the consumer key and secret key required?

document: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_authenticate_overview.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many OAuth flows, including the Web Server flow, provide a durable *refresh token*. A refresh token allows the remote application to request a new access token, usable to call the Salesforce API under the rubric of the original authorized user, with no additional intervention required by the user.

The JWT flow, as another example, creates a durable authenticated connection via a cryptographic certificate plus configuration in Salesforce setup. It *doesn't* come with a refresh token, but the pre-shared cryptographic certificate allows the remote application to re-authenticate and get a new access token at need. Again, no user interaction is required following the initial setup to allow the remote application to maintain its connection to Salesforce.

In every case, however, a Salesforce account must exist as the authenticated user. The client Id and secret identify the application, but are not credentials to allow access to Salesforce alone.

Comment: Nitpicking on the JWT aspect, the JWT flow still gives you an access token that's tied to the session timeout for the connected app (or for the org if it's not specified in the connected app). The access token here is durable as long as you always make a successful request before the session times out. If you miss the timeout, the access token is expired and you'd need to submit another JWT to get a new token.

Comment: @DerekF Yeah, I did not express that clearly. Thanks for the nudge.